# Return only the last value (country) in the column

Tags: r

I have the column "country":

1. Russia
2. Russia, USA
3. UK, USA, South Korea
4. South Korea

I'd like to get only the last country in this column:

1. Russia
2. USA
3. South Korea
4. South Korea

How can I separate this column to return only the last country (it may include 2 words like South Korea), extra countries should be dropped?

I tried to separate into 3 variables, but I think it'll be too long.
Also I tried to use "str_split" and "unlist" but can't write the correct code.

`df<-separate(df, country, into=c("v1","v2", "v3"), sep=",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can remove the substring with `trimws`

```
trimws(df$country, whitespace = ".*,\\s+")
[1] "Russia"      "USA"         "South Korea" "South Korea"
```

---

Or if we do the `strsplit/str_split`, the output is a `list`, thus we need to loop over the `list` to select the last element

```
sapply(strsplit(df$country, ",\\s*"), tail, 1)
[1] "Russia"      "USA"         "South Korea" "South Korea"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Russia", "Russia, USA", "UK, USA, South Korea", 
"South Korea")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <-
tibble(
  country = c("Russia","Russia, USA", "UK, USA, South Korea", "South Korea")
)  


df %>% 
  mutate(
   last_country = word(country,start = str_count(country,",") + 1,sep = ", ")
  )


# A tibble: 4 x 2
  country              last_country
  <chr>                <chr>       
1 Russia               Russia      
2 Russia, USA          USA         
3 UK, USA, South Korea South Korea 
4 South Korea          South Korea
```